# How to registre user in my own database through keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have been using keycloak for a very short time. made keycloak use my own user database and it works fine.
I would like new users who register to be registered directly in my database. So I implemented the `UseRegistrationProvider` class which contains the `addUser(RealmModel realm, String username)` and `removeUser(RealmModel realm, UserModel user)` methods. 
The problem is that in the `addUser` method I only have the username and I would like to have all the fields that have been filled on the registration form. How do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the addUser(...) method return an object implementing the UserModel. You will have to implement a UserModel adapter that enable to set the attributes you want.

See [Quickstart example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/user-storage-jpa/src/main/java/org/keycloak/quickstart/storage/user)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. What did i miss?

```
public class MyUserStorageProvider implements UserStorageProvider,
UserRegistrationProvider,
UserLookupProvider, 
UserQueryProvider, 
CredentialInputUpdater, 
CredentialInputValidator {

    private final KeycloakSession session;
    private final ComponentModel model;
    private final UserRepository repository;

    public MyUserStorageProvider(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model, UserRepository repository) {
        this.session = session;
        this.model = model;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public UserModel addUser(RealmModel realm, String username) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setEmail("I don't have email in addUser method");
        if(repository.addUser(user))
            return new UserAdapter(session, realm, model, user);
        else return null;
    }
}



public class UserAdapter extends AbstractUserAdapterFederatedStorage {

    private final User user;
    private final String keycloakId;

    public UserAdapter(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, ComponentModel model, User user) {
        super(session, realm, model);
        this.user = user;
        this.keycloakId = StorageId.keycloakId(model, user.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return keycloakId;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        user.setUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public String getEmail() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        user.setEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFirstName() {
        return user.getFirstName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getLastName() {
        return user.getLastName();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        user.setLastName(lastName);
    }
}


class UserRepository {

    private EntityManager em;

    public UserRepository(MultivaluedHashMap<String, String> config) {
        em = new JpaEntityManagerFactory(new Class[]{User.class}, config).getEntityManager();
    }
...

    boolean addUser(User user) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(user);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e) { 
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```